# python construct for protocol parsing

Tags: python, twisted, construct

I am trying to mix up the power of twisted `Protocol` with the ductility of `construct`, the declarative binary data parser.

So far, my `MessageReceiver` protocol accumulates the data coming from the tcp channel in the following way:

```
def rawDataReceived(self, data):
    '''
    This method bufferizes the data coming from the TCP channel in the following way:
        - Initially, discard the stream until a reserved character is detected
        - add data to the buffer up to the expected message length unless the reserved character is met again. In that case discard the message and start again
        - if the expected message length is reached, attempt to parse the message and clear the buffer
    '''
    if self._buffer:
        index = data.find(self.reserved_character)

        if index > -1:
            if len(self._buffer) + index >= self._fixed_size:
                self.on_message(self._buffer + data[:data.index(self._reserved_character)])

            self._buffer = b''
            data = data[data.index(self.reserved_character):]
            [self.on_message(chunks[:self._fixed_size]) for chunks in  [self.reserved_character + msg for msg in data.split(self._reserved_character) if msg]]

        elif len(self._buffer) + len(data) < self._expected_size:
            self._buffer = self._buffer + data
        else:
            self._buffer = b''
    else:  
        try:
            data = data[data.index(self._reserved_character):]
            [self.on_message(chunks[:self._fixed_size]) for chunks in  [self._reserved_character + msg for msg in data.split(self._reserved_character) if msg]]
        except Exception, exc:
            log.msg("Warning: Maybe there is no delimiter {delim} for the new message. Error: {err}".format(delim=self._reserved_character, err=str(exc)))
```

Now I am in need of evolving the protocol to take into consideration the fact that the message may or may not carry optional fields (thus there isn't a fixed message length anymore). I modeled (a meaningful part of) the message parser with `construct` in the following way:

```
def on_message(self, msg):
    return Struct(HEADER,
        Bytes(HEADER_RAW, 3),
        BitStruct(OPTIONAL_HEADER_STRUCT, 
            Nibble(APPLICATION_SELECTOR),
            Flag(OPTIONAL_HEADER_FLAG), 
            Padding(3)
        ),
        If(lambda ctx: ctx.optional_header_struct[OPTIONAL_HEADER_FLAG],
            Embed(Struct(None,
                   Byte(BATTERY_CHARGE),
                   Bytes(OPTIONAL_HEADER, 3)
                   )
            )
        )
    ).parse(msg)
```

So right now I am in need to change the buffering logic to pass the right chunk size to the `Struct`. I would like to avoid sizing up the data to be passed to the `Struct`in the `rawDataReceived` method considering that the rules of what is a possible candidate for a message are known in the `construct` object.

Is there any way to push the buffering logic to the `construct` object?

### Edit

I was able to partially achieved the aim to push the buffering logic inside, by simply making use of `Macro`s and `Adapter`s:

```
MY_PROTOCOL = Struct("whatever",
    Anchor("begin"),
    RepeatUntil(lambda obj, ctx:obj==RESERVED_CHAR, Field("garbage", 1)),
    NoneOf(Embed(HEADER_SECTION), [RESERVED_CHAR]),
    Anchor("end"),
    Value("size", lambda ctx:ctx.end - ctx.begin)
)
```

This greatly simplifies the caller code (which is no longer in `rawDataReceived` thanks to Glyph's suggestion):

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    log.msg('Received data: {}'.format(bytes_to_hex(data)))
    self._buffer += data
    try:
        container = My_PROTOCOL.parse(self._buffer)
        self._buffer = self._buffer[container.size:]
        d, self.d = self.d, self._create_new_transmission_deferred()
        d.callback(container)
    except ValidationError, err:
        self._cb_error("A validation error occurred. Discarding the rest of the message. {}".format(err))
        self._buffer = b''    
    except FieldError, err:     #Incomplete message. We simply keep on buffering and retry
        if len(self._buffer) >= MyMessageReceiver.MAX_GARBAGE_SIZE:
            self._cb_error("Buffer overflown. No delimiter found in the stream")
```

Unfortunately this solution covers the requirements only partially since I could not find a way to get `construct` to tell me the index of the stream that produced the error and therefore I am obliged to drop the entire buffer, which is not ideal.

Comment: `rawDataReceived` is a method on `LineReceiver`, not `Protocol`.  I think you want just `dataReceived`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `MessageReceiver` extends `LineReceiver`, that is what I meant

Comment: Why?  I don't see a `lineReceived` here, and `rawDataReceived` never calls `setLineMode`.

Comment: @Glyph: It is just the lose end of an incomplete refactoring, thanks for pointing it out. Indeed, instead of extending a `LineReceiver` and `setRawMode`, I'd better extend `Protocol` directly and override `dataReceived` instead

Comment: By the way, are you designing this protocol yourself, or are you parsing from something (from your example, I'm guessing an existing piece of hardware?)

Comment: I am designing the protocol myself

Answer (score 0):

To get the stream position at which an error occurs, you'll need to use Anchor and write your own version of NoneOf.  Assuming HEADER_SECTION is another Construct, replace the NoneOf like so:

```
SpecialNoneOf(Struct('example', Anchor('position'), HEADER_SECTION), [RESERVED_CHAR]))
```

SpecialNoneOf needs to subclass from Adapter and combine **init** and _validate from NoneOf with _encode and _decode from Validator.  In _decode, replace

```
raise ValidationError("invalid object", obj)
```

with

```
raise ValidationError("invalid object", obj.header_section + " at " + obj.position)
```

Replace header_section with the name of the HEADER_SECTION Construct.  You will have to change the structure of the resulting container or figure out a different way to use Embed to make this method work.